# download dynamically generated file from indirect url

Tags: vb.net

```
WebClient.DownloadFile(downloadLink,"report.csv")
```

doesn't work. Download link looks like

https://www.domain.com/report.asp?DataFile=TQHVQHSYPN.csv

where as the file which is being downloaded always comes from following type of URL

https://www.domain.com/net/DownloadManager.ashx?o=0&t=DE43035D

Seems like the downloadLink follows some redirects to get file from the second url where as I always have only downloadLink.

Is there a way to download files being followed by some redirects?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do this manually instead of using the convenience method `DownloadFile`. I'm not sure if it makes any difference, but perhaps try something like:

1. Creating a [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.HttpWebRequest.aspx) for the download link and make sure the [AllowAutoRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx) property is `true` (it should be by default anyway)
2. Use the [GetWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3xa6ys0.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method to get an [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) - you will probably need to cast the return value from `GetWebResponse` to a `HttpWebResponse`
3. Use something like [GetResponseStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) to download the file itself

Comment: I tried it this way but its returning login page. I passed cookies from my webbrowser control where I am already logged in but still no luck. Can you please have a look at the code I might have missed something. http://pastebin.com/5gYTdxNz

Comment: When you are setting the cookies what is the URL provided in `New Uri(url)`? Is this something like `https://www.domain.com/report.asp?DataFile=TQHVQHSYPN.csv`? If so, you probably want it to be the root of the site (e.g. `http://www.domain.com` or `https://www.domain.com`) rather than the URL you are trying to download from

Comment: Yeah it makes sense. I tried `request.CookieContainer.SetCookies(New Uri("https://www.domian.com"), WebBrowser1.Document.Cookie)` as well and its still showing login page

Comment: There may be some incompatibility as [CookieContainer.SetCookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.setcookies.aspx) wants the cookies to be comma delimited but what you get out of the `WebBrowser1.Document.SetCookie` property is apparently [semi-colon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.cookie.aspx) delimited....you may need to rip the cookies apart manually and then put them together or have your WebClient login first (e.g. via doing a POST against the login page) and then do the download request

Comment: smart man!! does this make sense `request.CookieContainer.SetCookies(New Uri("https://www.domian.com"), New String(cookie).Replace(";", ","))`

Comment: Looks ok, you shouldn't need to do `New String(cookie)` though as `Replace` gives you a new string anyway, e.g. you could do `cookie.Replace(...)`. Good luck!

Comment: You may want to try the more involved way where you use the `WebClient` to login (e.g. by POSTing against the login page), grab the cookies out of the `HttpWebResponse` and use them in the `HttpWebRequest` you use to download the file. Other than that, I'm not sure what else to try...sorry

Comment: I also tried that but stupid server is not letting me login. Any ways thank you so much for your help :)